# Is it possible to be able to have two modal windows on the same page using only HTML and CSS?

Tags: html, css

I want to be able to get two different popup windows that can open and close using different links on the same page using only HTML and CSS, no Javascript. Is this possible and how?

Comment: Please show us what you have so far.

Comment: What kind of _"popup windows"_? Bootstrap modals, JS prompts? Show your code

Answer (score 0):

TL; DR: **NO**

## Explanation

You intend to display a modal and it can be done via a link click via pseudo-selectors, such as [active](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active). If your modal is structurally inside the structure that serves the purpose of the link, then you could have a pseudo-selector, such as

```
.your-modal {
    display: none;
}

.your-wrapper:active > .your-modal {
    display: block;
}
```

But once you activate your other link, this modal will disappear, unless you have a similar link with a similar modal nested into this one. But it is difficult to imagine real-life usage for this kind of thing.